# Prevent collection returning array with index or without index depending on the input after filtering

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-collection, laravel-6.2

I mentioned this strange behavior on filtering my collection.

Let's assume I got this array:

```
 [
       "value" => 1,
       "available" => false,
     ],
     [
       "value" => 3,
       "available" => false,
     ],
     [
       "value" => 6,
       "available" => false,
     ],
     [
       "value" => 12,
       "available" => true,
     ],
     [
       "value" => 24,
       "available" => false,
     ],
```

If I now use this to filter all elements where available is `true`:

```
collect($prod->items)->filter(function (
                $item
            ) {
                if (is_array($item)) {
                    return $item['available'] === true;
                }
                if (is_object($item)) {
                    return $item->available === true;
                }

                return false;
            });
```

i am getting this result:

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1010
     all: [
       3 => [
         "value" => 12,
         "available" => true,
       ],
     ],
   }
```

If there's more than one item `true`, I am getting this result:

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1006
     all: [
       [
         "value" => 1,
         "available" => true,
       ],
       [
         "value" => 3,
         "available" => true,
       ],
       [
         "value" => 6,
         "available" => true,
       ],
       [
         "value" => 12,
         "available" => true,
       ],
       [
         "value" => 24,
         "available" => true,
       ],
     ],
   }
```

Did you see that the index (first example: `3`) is missing here? How can I always be sure that there's no index?

The reason I need this: I am using the result in an API response that is used by a vue-app. The vue-app iterates over the array and prints the value - but if the result is prefixed with an additional key, the app crashes.

Comment: Could you explain the use case in which you do not want it? Could be useful for submitting a correct answer. You might be looking for the [`values()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-values) method.

Comment: That's already the solution. I just wanted to remove the index and wondered why this is added in one case and not in the other.

Comment: What you need? It's normal

Comment: I added my requirement in my initial question.